# How do I remove a hover effect in Squarespace?

Tags: css, hover, squarespace

So I can't figure out how to remove the hover effect on a friends site I'm working on...I don't want to see the hover background on the arrows here:

http://adam-smith-0nvq.squarespace.com/drawings-paintings

The hover effect shows up here: http://d.pr/i/SyYt

How can I change it so there is no hover on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With prescriptive questions like this, I'd always suggest inspecting the element and posting the relevant code snippets along with your question. Often, you figure out these basic CSS issues in doing so.

Put this in your custom CSS document:

```
.sqs-gallery-controls .next:hover,
.sqs-gallery-controls .previous:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

If you inspected this element, you would see that SquareSpace has a `.next` and a `.previous` class on these arrows. Both of these classes have rules applying to their *pseudo-class* `:hover`. So basically they used `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);` on this pseudo-class, creating that transparent black background.

Override it by inserting the CSS above so that, on hover, the element inherits its class's primary background rule, being nothing (or anything that you change it to in the future).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `background-color` to **transparent** on hover

```
.sqs-gallery-controls.show-hover-effect a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```